# ViewController does not have a member named managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to use coredata in a popoverpresentationviewcontroller but it keeps saying that my view controller called PopoverVC does not have a member named managedObjectContext.

I have tried:

**1. Initializing inside init for PopoverViewController:**

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as! AppDelegate
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
}
```

**2. Passing it from another view controller where I simply got it from calling App Delegate**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    switch(segue.identifier!) {
        case "popOverSegue":
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! PopoverVC
            controller.managedObjectContext  = self.managedObjectContext!
            break
        default:
            break
     }
}
```

Normally I can just access it in any other view controller by using:

```
((UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Which I heard maybe bad practice, but this won't even work in this popover view controller. None of the solutions on other stackoverflow questions work either.

EDIT, below is how my PopoverViewController class looks like, including all of it to make sure it isn't a stupid syntax mistake somewhere breaking the code. I am now declaring managedObjectContext as getter property. Still same error.

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var testingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var aPicker: UIPickerView!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //cancel button
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "tapCancel:")

    // popover settings
    modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:400,height:600)
}

//var appDelegate: AppDelegate
//var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObject
var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
}

var pickerData = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue","Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Region")


var fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Region]
//pickerData = fetchResults

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
    //return pickerData[row]
}

@IBInspectable var popoverOniPhone:Bool = false
@IBInspectable var popoverOniPhoneLandscape:Bool = true

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(PC: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{

    //this methods is only called by System when the screen has compact width

    //return .None means we still want popover when adaptive on iPhone
    //return .FullScreen means we'll get modal presetaion on iPhone

    switch(popoverOniPhone, popoverOniPhoneLandscape){
    case (true, _): // always popover on iPhone
        return .None

    case (_, true): // popover only on landscape on iPhone
        let size = PC.presentingViewController.view.frame.size
        if(size.width>320.0){ //landscape
            return .None
        }else{
            return .FullScreen
        }

    default: // no popover on iPhone
        return .FullScreen
    }


}

func presentationController(_: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle _: UIModalPresentationStyle)
    -> UIViewController?{
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
}

func tapCancel(_ : UIBarButtonItem) {
    //tap cancel
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you declared a property variable `managedObjectContext` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I had. Using the line: 
managedObjectContext: NSManagedObject?

I would figure it would definitely work with declaring a property only to crash on run if it isn't initialized or give an error before compiling that not initialized. But it keeps insisting that the class "does not have a member named managedObjectContext"

Comment: Please edit your question to show the class definition for `PopoverViewController` including this property definition, because the compiler is saying you don't have it

Comment: @Paulw11 now edited the question to include class definition and property definition. It has to be some foolish mistake as compiler should not give an error unless it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `managedObjectContext` as a read-only computed property, so you cannot assign a value to it.

To use the assignment that you have in `prepareForSegue` you need to make it a straight-forward optional property -

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
```

Comment: This was declared in the PopoverViewController class exactly as above and the same class appears to not be able to find it. "'PopoverViewcontroller.Type' does not have a member named managedObjectContext"

Comment: I copied your class into a Playground and could reference `self.managedObjectContext`.    You will have  a problem with `fetchResults` because it will try to use `managedObjectContext` before it has a value